# Migrate String from Java class to resources

Tags: java, android, string, android-resources

I working in a Quiz Question.

I have on "Questions.java"

```
package com.example.luisbalmant.quickquiz_science;

import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by LuisBalmant on 15/07/2017.
 */

public class Questions {
    public String mQuestions[] = {
            "My question here",


    };
}
```

I'm trying use string language of "strings.xml" on "My question here".

Eg:

```
<string name="Q1_function_insulin">What is the function of insulin?</string>
```

I'm trying this:

```
getString(R.string.Q1_function_insulin),
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `Context` object in order to perform `getString()`. Thus, you can refactor your class this way:

```
    public class Questions {

        private static final int QUESTIONS[] = {
                R.string.text1,
                R.string.text2
        };

        private Context context;

        public Questions(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public String getString(int index) {
            return context.getString(QUESTIONS[index]);
        }
    }
```

And then, from your activity:

```
Questions questions = new Questions(MainActivity.this);
questions.getString(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right, i assume you want to load all questions from the strings.xml file and place them inside the mQuestions array. What you wrote there (`getString(R.string.Q1_function_insulin)`) should work without any problem. I suggest that you put all your questions in an array inside the xml and load the whole array at once with `getStringArray(R.array.questions)`.

Comment: Oh and also, next time please say where the exact problem is and what part of your code is not working. If possible, attach logs and stack traces.

Comment: Thanks. I try use "(getString(R.string.Q1_function_insulin)), " but is not working. I erased everything and rewrote it. I did not succeed.

Comment: You need a context to get resources from xml. If you try to call getString() in the Questions-class, there is no such method. Try loading the questions inside an Activity or pass a valid context to Questions to you can call getString() on the resource returned from context.getResources(). Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Comment: Thank you dedda1994. Now that's ok.